# Hibernate spatial API query for Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I tried to use spatial API in Spring boot.

- I am able to save the SDO_GEOMETRY data types into **oracle** database.
- I am able to retrieve it using SQL query,
- Only problem is If I use with Hibernate APIs it throws an error (don't want to use SQL)

**I tested following SQL query it works fine, so the problem not in database**

```
SELECT
    s.ID,
    s.LOCATION
FROM PORTS s
where SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE(
              s.LOCATION,
              SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307,
                           SDO_POINT_TYPE( 24.817768,46.599417, NULL),NULL, NULL
                  ),
              'distance=10 unit=KM'
          ) = 'TRUE';
```

**My Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ports")
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JpaPort {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
 @Column(name = "location",columnDefinition="SDO_GEOMETRY")
    private Geometry location;
    private String name;
}
```

**My repository query:**

```
 portRepository.findAll(filterWithinRadius(portDTO.getLat(), portDTO.getLon(), portDTO.getRangeInMeters()));
```

**Specification for this:**

```
public static Specification<JpaPort> filterWithinRadius(double latitude, double longitude, double radius) {
        return new Specification<JpaPort>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<JpaPort> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();

                Geometry comparisonPoint = factory.createPoint(new Coordinate(latitude,longitude));

                comparisonPoint.setSRID(8307);

               Expression<Geometry> dbPoint = root.get("location").as(Geometry.class);
                Expression<Boolean> expression = builder.function("SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE", boolean.class,
                        dbPoint, builder.literal(comparisonPoint),builder.literal("DISTANCE=1 UNIT=MILE"));
                return builder.equal(expression, true);
            }
        };
    }
```

If I'm using Hibernate I got following error

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

 oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I don't know my this approach is correct/wrong, because I'm new to spring development, if you have any other solution feel free to answer or comment.

Is there any other way to make the Spatial API query in Hibernate?

My source code - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1loSLFg3Cok9iwtv3apXP3f59QiJdI2eS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `return builder.equal(expression, true)` - there is no boolean datatype in oracle, moreover, your initial SQL deals with varchar `'TRUE'`

Comment: @Olivier ok got it. I'm new to spring development. I added the JPA tag

Comment: Now you should follow Andrey's advice and fix the return type of `SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compare the result against the varchar `'TRUE'`, just like in your SQL example. Use this:

```
Expression<String> expression = builder.function("SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE", String.class,
    dbPoint, builder.literal(comparisonPoint),builder.literal("DISTANCE=1 UNIT=MILE"));
return builder.equal(expression, "TRUE");
```